# rqt_graph is not working

Tags: ros-noetic, rqt-graph

---

### My Ubuntu version is 20.04 . My ROS version is noetic 1.16.0 . My python version is 3.8.10 .

When I use command "rqt_graph" in the terminal, it shows a blank GUI window, displaying nothing and with the error messages as below:

```
PluginHandlerDirect._restore_settings() plugin "rqt_graph/RosGraph#0" raised an exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/ros/noetic/lib/python3/dist-packages/qt_gui/plugin_handler_direct.py", line 121, in _restore_settings
    self._plugin.restore_settings(plugin_settings_plugin, instance_settings_plugin)
  File "/opt/ros/noetic/lib/python3/dist-packages/rqt_graph/ros_graph.py", line 260, in restore_settings
    self._refresh_rosgraph()
  File "/opt/ros/noetic/lib/python3/dist-packages/rqt_graph/ros_graph.py", line 289, in _refresh_rosgraph
    self._update_graph_view(self._generate_dotcode())
  File "/opt/ros/noetic/lib/python3/dist-packages/rqt_graph/ros_graph.py", line 308, in _generate_dotcode
    return self.dotcode_generator.generate_dotcode(
  File "/opt/ros/noetic/lib/python3/dist-packages/rqt_graph/dotcode.py", line 893, in generate_dotcode
    dotgraph = self.generate_dotgraph(
  File "/opt/ros/noetic/lib/python3/dist-packages/rqt_graph/dotcode.py", line 675, in generate_dotgraph
    [n for n in nn_nodes if matches_any(n, includes) and not matches_any(n, excludes)]
  File "/opt/ros/noetic/lib/python3/dist-packages/rqt_graph/dotcode.py", line 675, in <listcomp>
    [n for n in nn_nodes if matches_any(n, includes) and not matches_any(n, excludes)]
  File "/opt/ros/noetic/lib/python3/dist-packages/rqt_graph/dotcode.py", line 79, in matches_any
    if re.match(unicode(pattern), name.strip()) is not None:
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/re.py", line 191, in match
    return _compile(pattern, flags).match(string)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/re.py", line 304, in _compile
    p = sre_compile.compile(pattern, flags)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/sre_compile.py", line 764, in compile
    p = sre_parse.parse(p, flags)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/sre_parse.py", line 940, in parse
    source = Tokenizer(str)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/sre_parse.py", line 232, in __init__
    self.__next()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/sre_parse.py", line 245, in __next
    raise error("bad escape (end of pattern)",
re.error: bad escape (end of pattern) at position 0
```

It happened last week. I was able to use it before that.
I googled it but cannot find the same problem and tried a lot of things to fix it but failed finally.
Part of things I found on the Internet and I tried but cannot work:
reinstall ros-noetic-rqt-graph;
reinstall ros-noetic;
command "sudo dot -c";
reinstall pydot pyparsing
...

Answer (score 0):

Try doing a "clean build" of your catkin_ws. Python caches .pyc files in `catkin_ws/devel/lib/python3/`, and if you've updated your ros install using apt, there may now be old, incompatible files in the tree.

To do a clean build for `catkin_make`: in the top-level of your catkin_ws, delete the `devel` and `build` directories. Then re-run your `catkin_make` command.